# Group_by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show my posts posted according to days (dates). Can anyone help me on this I will be very grateful.

```
Def index
 @users = User.all
end
```

I want my output according to date.
User can store post.title and post.content but i want all the posts according to dates as below

Example:

```
2nd December
post1
post2
post3

3rd December
post4
post5

4th December
no post
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@grouped_posts = Post.group("date(created_at)")
```

or you can also do

```
Post.all.group_by {|post| post.created_at.to_date}
```

Documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)